# Why proxy and Object.create don't work together

Tags: javascript, html

when i do this like below, i always get "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded", but i just aceess to receiver, it will be ok if i delete `console.log(receiver);` , very confused.

```js
const someObject = {};
const proxy6 = new Proxy(someObject, {
  get(target, prop, receiver) {
    console.log(receiver);
    return 111;
  },
});

const derived = Object.create(proxy6);
console.log(derived.someProperty);
```

i try use Object.assign() to wrap proxy, it's ok.

Comment: It would help if you explain (1) why you are doing this and (2) what you are trying to achieve. People could help to try fix this strange issue, but there may be better, totally different solutions which people can't give unless they know about your reasons and goals.

Comment: That just happens because `console.log` wants to get information from the given `receiver` object, accessing its properties, so it can show a nice representation, but since `receiver` is `derived`, it means `get` is called again, leading to infinite recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour is implementation-dependent. For instance, Firefox (I'm running version 108) has no issue with this code, and just prints an object representation in the console:

[image]

In Chrome/Edge, the console implementation wants to retrieve some object properties of the object it gets to print, including `[Symbol.toStringTag]`. But since `receiver` is `derived` this initiates the proxy's `get` handler again, leading to infinite recursion.

To avoid this, make your handler code conditional: determine exactly when you want to execute that `console.log` and return 111.

So do something like this:

```js
const someObject = {};
const proxy6 = new Proxy(someObject, {
  get(target, prop, receiver) {
    if (["someProperty"].includes(prop)) { // Add more props as desired...
        console.log(receiver);
        return 111;
    }
    return Reflect.get(target, name); // default
  },
});

var derived = Object.create(proxy6);
console.log(derived.someProperty);
```